# How can i copy text to a richbox from a text file?

Tags: c#

I want to copy the text from a .txt file into a richbox when the form loads.
I don't want to open a dialog to choose the file, just open a specific file automatically

```
 Stream sr;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((sr = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string commandstext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
                richTextBox2.Text=commandstext;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What `error/problem` are you facing?

Comment: This is the method with opening a filedialog. But i don't want to open a filedialog, i don't know how to make that the Form copy the text from that textfile in my richbox automatically, when it loads.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do as suggested in other 2 answers.

**OR** other *`faster`* way as:

```
void LoadFileToRTB(string fileName, RichTextBox rtb)
{
  rtb.LoadFile(File.OpenRead(fileName), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); // second parameter you can change to fit for you
  // or
  rtb.LoadFile(fileName);
  // or
  rtb.LoadFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText); // second parameter you can change to fit for you
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Stream sr;
    string strfilename = "PATH TO FILE"; //Code should know the path already
    string commandstext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
    richTextBox2.Text=commandstext;
```

Comment: What's the default path? I mean project/debug/?

Comment: for exe location path  `string strfilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "filename");`

Comment: And if i want each time i modify the text from the "Specific textfile" my loaded form load automaticaly the text? Like editing live in text file, and the form loads automaticaly what i write in that textfile.

Comment: @DonTzapone You need much more than that if you want to dynamically refresh depending on changes made on the source file. You will File System Watcher!

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("YourFilePath.txt"))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            richTextBox2.Text=line;
        }
```

Comment: Using the "using" will take care of closing the file once you done with it.

Comment: What's the defaut filepath?I mean in my debug's application folder?

Comment: I think the default is your bin folder, but you can try this to get the application folder:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory